# Does aws:sourceVpce filters request not using VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc

I'd like to filter access to S3 outside from specific VPC, and planning to apply policy like [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/block-s3-traffic-vpc-ip/?nc1=h_ls).

In this case, by using `aws:sourceVpce` in `Condition`, we can filter out access except from specific VPC endpoint.

But my S3 bucket has another policy to allow access from other AWS service in order to store log. And I'm worried if these access will be filtered too or not.
I read [document about aws:sourceVpce](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-sourcevpce), and it says `This key is included in the request context only if the requester uses a VPC endpoint to make the request.` .

Does this means `aws:sourceVpce` doesn't filter request which is not using VPC endpoint, or any kind of request except using a specific VPC endpoint is filtered?

Answer (score 0):

If any permission specifically declares `Deny`, if a request matches that Deny the output will always be Deny.

If you wanted to block all access unless one of multiple conditions has met, you would need to include all those conditions in the deny statement.

Then include additional allow statements for the specific policies based on conditions. You would have your global deny, then an allow for the VPCE and an allow statement for the services.